# Database: Sharing two sets of values in a single table?

Tags: database, share

I'll start by saying I am not a DBA and I didn't get to do heavy database development so far (so I hope I'm not asking something obvious).

**The Challenge:**

1. I have a dictionary application with pre-defined values.
2. New values may be added via online updates.
3. Users are not allowed to modify these application-values, but they may add/delete values of their own.
4. The database (sqlite3) will contain a small amount of values (~2K-3K).
5. The database schema is exactly the same for both user and application values.

**Possible solutions:**

- One way to go about it would be to create two different tables having the same schema, and JOIN the data from both tables when querying the database.
- A different approach would be to have a single table in which application-values will start at ID=0, and user-values will start at ID=100000 (for example). Online updates will merge new values below ID=100000 such that user values will remain intact.

I prefer the second solution - it'll avoid JOINs during runtime and the queries will remain simple.
However, an update to the application-values in the first solution would require me to just replace the application table with the new one.

**Please let me know what you think:**

- Which solution is better?
- What are the pros/cons that I'm missing?
- Is there an even-better *third* solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just a column 'type' to your table and fill it with user/application?

Personaly I hate meaningfull ID's....

Comment: I also thought about this, but my baseline is the application-values table. This should look the same in any database, so in order to correctly merge new values only, I want to get the max ID number below 100000 (e.g. 591) and insert all the new values (e.g. [592..614]) into it.
That's why I have this 100000 initial placeholder.

Comment: So, assuming I use the 'type' column, how should I merge new application-values to an existing database? Delete all of them and re-insert? Add a UID for each row and insert the ones that are missing? (this one's pulling again to the above suggested notion)

Comment: If you are using Sql server 2008 you can use the merge command http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: That just about wraps it up. Thanks for your help.